# Метод класса BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler setup которого нет в документации

Tags: python, сервер, http, веб-сервер

Читал чужой код сервера на с использованием модуля `BaseHTTPServer`. Там создаётся наследник:

```
class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
...
```

Внутри метода экземпляра класса `RequestHandler` вызывается метод класса setup:

```
r=BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.setup(self)
```

Почитал документацию, но так и не нашёл этого метода. Подскажите, где прочитать, что за метод такой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `setup()` [объявлен в классе `SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c3642219090f2564c1790330cbf0ba31f19dcaf4/Lib/SocketServer.py#L659-L660) и [имплементирован в классе `SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c3642219090f2564c1790330cbf0ba31f19dcaf4/Lib/SocketServer.py#L698-L706), от которого и наследует `BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler`.

В доках:

[`SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.setup`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler.setup):

> **setup()**
>
> Called before the `handle()` method to perform any initialization actions required. The default implementation does nothing.